# Uri function 'contains' with a parent token. Uri functions cannot have parent tokens

Tags: odata

Im am trying to use the contains function in a filter against a Navigation Property that is not a collection. But I cannot get it to work

https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(5cduegdbizijxzaeonro1qmc))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$select=UserName&$filter=Photo/contains(Name, 'e')

This errors with " Uri function 'contains' with a parent token. Uri functions cannot have parent tokens."

However I can get it to work for properties on Navigation properties that ARE Collections.

https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(5cduegdbizijxzaeonro1qmc))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$select=UserName&$filter=Friends/any(a: contains(a/UserName, 'e'))

And both the above examples work when using eq rather than contains

https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(5cduegdbizijxzaeonro1qmc))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$select=UserName&$filter=Friends/any(a: a/UserName eq 'e')

and

https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(5cduegdbizijxzaeonro1qmc))/TripPinServiceRW/People?$select=UserName&$filter=Photo/Name eq 'e'

What am I missing??
Thanks v much

Comment: I believe the reason your first one didn't work was because you selected the UserName BEFORE you filtered. Does it work if you filter and then select?